# record the computation time for each epoch during model.fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using the standard `keras` process to train a model:

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 50)
```

And the output is something like:

```
Epoch 1/50
52/52 [==============================] - 8s 90ms/step - loss: 0.0027
Epoch 2/50
52/52 [==============================] - 5s 90ms/step - loss: 0.0023
```

How can I calculate elapsed time for each Epoch?

I will have more than one experiment so I want to compare times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a simple custom callback. Documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/) My code to do that is shown below

```
import time
class etimer(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__ (self): # initialization of the callback
        super(etimer, self).__init__()
    def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch, logs=None):
        self.now= time.time()
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch, logs=None): 
        later=time.time()
        duration=later-self.now 
        print('\nfor epoch ', epoch +1, ' the duration was ', duration, ' seconds')
```

in model.fit add  callbacks=callbacks

Comment: SAME NOTHING CHANGE                                                                                                                  Epoch 1/2
52/52 [==============================] - 10s 127ms/step - loss: 0.0050
Epoch 2/2
52/52 [==============================] - 7s 127ms/step - loss: 0.0041
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x1faac9c9fd0>

Comment: I tested my code and it works fine. If you want more help post your code

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it, would be to [write your own training callback inheriting from the Callback class](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/).

You then need to override the methods `on_epoch_begin()` and `on_epoch_end()` which are called by `model.fit()` during training. There you can start and end counters, and save the results to internal variables to access them later.

---

But wouldn't it be easier to simple measure the time of the whole training process and divide by the number of epochs? (Although, that would also take into account the validation time)

Comment: how is that i dont know please write it

Comment: I am sorry, this is not accepted for a stack overflow question. You have to show us what you tried and what specifically you cannot understand. Otherwise you want us to do the work for you.